# Is plugin 'gridexporter' working for anyone in Extjs 6.0.1?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I'm trying to implement export to excel from grid in Extjs grid. I see that we have a exporter plugin (ptype: 'gridexporter') mentioned in the documentation, but I am unable to use it with Ext.grid.Panel. Is anyone else facing the same issue or know how to resolve it?

Thanks,
Sujam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, someone was facing the same issue and some Sencha guy knew how to resolve it.](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?305642-Ext.grid.plugin.Exporter-missing-in-Ext-6.0.1)

> The exporter plugin is available with Ext JS Premium.

Comment: That was really helpful. We've a Ext JS Premium Edition membership though.

Thanks!